# Regex match - two words with any three characters in between except comma and full stop?

Tags: regex

Two words, aaa and bbb need to be found in the text. There can be any three characters in between these words, for instance:

- `"aaa-bbb"`
- `"aaa  bbb"`
- `"aaa - bbb"`
- `"aaa- bbb"`
- `"aaa -bbb"`

etc. All these must result in a match.

However, if there is comma or a full stop, there should be no match. For instance:

- `"aaa.bbb"`
- `"aaa,bbb"`
- `"aaa, bbb"`
- `"aaa ,bbb"`
- `"aaa . bbb"`
- `"aaa , bbb"`

etc. must not be found in the text.

Essentially what I am doing is trying to find all possible "aaa bbb" occurrences in the text, even if there are typos.

"aaa. Bbb" or "aaa, bbb" have a different meaning, therefore must not be found.

Please help in formulating RegEx.

Edit: its for Python.

Comment: Well, what do you have so far?

Comment: And what programming language are you using? Each supports different reg ex features.

Comment: What do you mean with any? Is `c` also allowed (like `aaacbbb`?)

Comment: Yes, "c" can be there too.

Answer (score 3):

This regex should do it:

```
aaa[^,.]{0,3}bbb
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/oZ1gS2/9)

Comment: @user3013157 this will match `aaaabbb` too